# Remote sessions limited to two of many monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

I have 3 monitors attached to my local PC arranged in a triangle.
My goal is to have the top monitor display local content, while displaying a remote session across the bottom two. I have gotten this to work with span and RDP, but I am looking for a software that would allow the remote sessions to be restricted to a number of monitors of my choosing, rather than spanning.

Does this software exist? I've looked extensively. If there is a hack or something that might do it, I'm totally down for getting my hands dirty.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried Royal TS?
A good program with a lot of functions.

You can find it @ http://www.royalts.com/main/home/win.aspx

Source: My own expirience.

Scott

Comment: How does Royal TS solve the problem of using a subset of many monitors?